# Default select drop-down-menu in php

Tags: php, mysql

So i have 3 tables, 2 with data and 1 to connect the other 2 through foreign keys.
It's something like this:

```
student(ID_stud, etc)
specialization(ID_spec,spec_name)
study(ID_stud,ID_spec, etc)
```

Now i'm working at an Edit.php menu(i did the add menu with the list) and i need specializations in a drop-down-menu with the value from the mysql already selected

Here is what i did so far but i only get the correct value selected repeating itself n times

```
<select name="specialization" type="text">
        <?php
        $specialization=$_POST['specialization'];
        $list_spec=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM specialization, study, student WHERE $ID_stud=study.ID_stud and specialization.ID_spec=study.ID_spec ");
        $array_spec=mysql_fetch_array($list_spec);
        while ($array_spec = mysql_fetch_array($list_spec)){?>
        <option selected="<? echo $array_spec['ID_spec'] ?>"><?php echo $array_spec['spec_name'];?></option>
        <?php }?>
        </select>
```

Comment: please don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: I dont worry about this since it's for a project, it wont end up on the web so i try to keep it as simple as possible

Comment: It's hard to change bad habbits, why won't you use PDO or MySQLi even if it's for a project ? As for your question, you should post the output of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the `selected` attribute on the item that is selected. All the others will not have a `selected` attribute. The value of this attribute does not matter.

Something like this:

```
<option <? if(isSelected) echo 'selected' ?>><?php echo $array_spec['spec_name'];?></option>
```